# Why use Static Intent Methods in Android

Tags: android, performance, android-intent

I am learning from the book android programming the big nerd ranch guide, in which author writes Static Intent Methods for passing data between activities, Although i know how code works but complete clueless about the logic and reason behind it.

```
public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext, boolean answerIsTrue){
    Intent i = new Intent(packageContext,CheatActivity.class);
    i.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE,answerIsTrue);
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a [mcve] demonstrating the code that you do not understand.

Comment: @CommonsWare i have updates the answer with the demonstrating code mentioned in the book and thanks for correction

Comment: You forgot to tell what the author tells about its goal.

Comment: @greenapps he is passing data to another activity using static intent. I think that's kind of very big goal :D

Comment: You misunderstood. We all know that intents are used to transfer data. But i asked what the goal was of a static function to create an intent. So first you can ask why to make a function for these code lines? Well as usual the reason is to have less code lines if you need the result often. And why make it static? Well to be able to use the function from different classes easily.

Comment: `in which author writes Static Intent Methods for passing data between activities`. No. The author uses static methods which return an Intent instance to make your life easy. That intents are used to transfer data is irrelevant in this context.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you mean he writes functions like:

```
  public static Intent createIntent(param1, param2) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(param1);
    intent.putExtra(param2);
    return intent;
  }
```

The reason to do that is to show what parameter an Activity requires to work and to have a single function you can call to create an Intent for that activity, rather than have to replicate that logic in a dozen places where you start the activity in the app.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the static method Android studio produces when you type "starter"

```
public static void start(Context context) {
    Intent starter = new Intent(context, SomeActivity.class);
    starter.putExtra(EXTRA_SOME_EXTRA, "some_extra_String");
    context.startActivity(starter);
}
```

which you can then expand to specify exactly which parameters should become extras or what request code.

```
public static void startForResult(Activity activity, String name, int requestCode) {
    Intent starter = new Intent(activity, SomeActivity.class);
    starter.putExtra(EXTRA_SOME_EXTRA, name);
    activity.startActivityForResult(starter, requestCode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the book itself:

This static method allows us to create an Intent properly configured with the extras CheatActivity will need. The answerIsTrue argument, a boolean, is put into the intent with a private name using the EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE constant. You will extract this value momentarily. Using a newIntent(…) method like this for your activity subclasses will make it easy for other code to properly configure their launching intents.